# How do you use jest to test a function inside React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

How do I test restrictMaxLength in my textfield component? It is called onInput and I want to check that it is returning the correct values. How can I call restrictMaxLength in my jest test?

```js
export default function StoreIDTextField(props: any) {
  const { onValueChanged } = props;
  // @ts-ignore
  const classes:any = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState<State>({
    name: 'Cat in the Hat',
    age: null,
  });

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const handleChange = (name: keyof State) => (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: event.target.value });
    onValueChanged(event.target.value);
  };

  function restrictMaxLength(e: any) {
    return Math.max(0, parseInt((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value)).toString().slice(0, 3);
  }

  return (
    <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
        type="number"
        onInput={(e) => {
          // restricts maxLength of store number to 3 digits
          // eslint-disable-next-line max-len,radix
          (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value = restrictMaxLength(e);
        }}
        required
        id="outlined-number"
        onChange={handleChange('age')}
        value={values.age}
        label="Store ID"
        defaultValue=""
        className={classes.textField}
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's an internal implementation detail; it's not accessible from outside, and that's a good thing. Make sure that the resulting value is what it ought to be.

Comment: Do I not use wrapper.instance() to call restrictMaxLength? What would be the correct way to do so? Thanks!

Comment: No, because it's not a property of the instance. Simulating input should trigger the function.

Comment: You wouldn't test that function directly. You would instead validate the end result, perhaps in this case that `value` is what you expect after an input event has been simulated. Test the end result of the input event in terms of changes to props/state/attributes/etc. Otherwise move the function to a different file where it's exported, which would allow you to import/use in the component as well as test individually.

Comment: Ok I see. However, wrapper.props().value is undefined when I use it, would that be how I test the end result?

Comment: How would I actually validate the end result because simulate does not actually go through onInput and call restrictMaxLength? So getDOMNode().getAttribute('value') would just be exactly what value I gave simulate.